# Using timestamp as an Attribute in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm quite new to DynamoDB, but have some experience in Cassandra.  I'm trying to adapt a pattern I followed in Cassandra, where each column represented a timestamped event, and wondering if it will carry over gracefully into DynamoDB or if I need to change my approach.

My goal is to query a set of documents within a date range by using the milliseconds-since-epoch timestamp as an Attribute name.  I'm successfully storing the following as each report is generated with each new report being added under its own column:

```
{ PartitionKey:customerId,
  SortKey:reportName_yyyymm,
  '#millis_1#':{'report':doc_1},
  '#millis_2#':{'report':doc_2},
  . . .
  '#millis_n#':{'report':doc_n}
}
```

My question is, given a millisecond-based date range, and the accompanying Partition and Sort keys, is it possible to query the set of Attributes that fall within that range or must I retrieve all columns for the matching keys and filter them at the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the most powerful NoSQL database ;)

To kick off with the positive news, there is no way to query out specific attributes. You can project certain attributes in a query. But you would have to write your own logic to determine which attributes or columns should be included in the projected query. To get close to your solution you could use a map attribute inside an item with the milliseconds as a key. But there is another thing you have to be aware of when starting on this path.

There is a maximum total item size of 400KB for each item in DynamoDB, including key and attribute names.([Limits in DynamoDB Items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-items%22Limits%20in%20DynamoDB%20Items%22)) This means you can only store so many attributes in an item. This is especially true if you intend to put the actual report inside of the attribute. Which I would advise against, also because you will be burning up read capacity units every time you get one attribute out of the whole item. You would be better of putting this data in a separate table with the keys in the map. But truthfully in DynamoDB I would split this whole thing up, just add the milliseconds to the sort key and make every document its own item. That way you can directly query to these items and you can use the "between" where clause to select specific date-time ranges. Please let me you meant something else.